# How can I print an array in chunks with a delimeter as the last character of the line in all but the last line

Tags: arrays, perl

I have the following:

```
my @array = qw/a b c d e f g h i j/;  
my $elements_per_line =4;
```

I need the output to look like this:

```
a | b | c | d |
e | f | g | h |
i | j
```

I have tried this:

```
while (@array) { 
    print join " | ", splice(@array, 0, $elements_per_line), "\n";
}
```

But that results in the " | " at the end of all 3 lines.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
my @array = qw/a b c d e f g h i j/;
my $elements_per_line =4;

while (@array) {
  print join " | ", splice(@array, 0, $elements_per_line);
  print " |" if @array;
  print "\n";
}
```

Comment: Hmm, with that, I get a result where none of the lines have the " | " on the end.

Comment: Did you copy it correctly?  Especially the `print " |" if @array;` line?  It works fine here.  Or did you mean you need a space at the end of the line?  If so, add the space to `" |"`.

Comment: Apparently I am "notagoodreader" either...that did work! THank you so much!

Answer (score -1):

How about a solution not using join or splice?

```
my $count = 0;
foreach my $element (@array) {
   print "$element | ";
   $count++;
   if (($count % $elements_per_line) == 0) {
       print "\n";
   }
}
```

Don't know if it's as efficient as the `split`/`join`, but it is easier to understand.

Comment: Except that it has the same problem as the original code: it puts a `|` after the final element.  And it introduces a new bug: it doesn't print a newline after the final element (unless the number of elements is a multiple of `$elements_per_line`).